# How to retrieve deployment targets id's in Octopus

Tags: octopus-deploy

I have 10 deployment targets in Octopus, and five of them has a role name "Web Server". Can anybody help me how to retrieve the id's of the machines which contains role name "Web Server" with powershell script?

Comment: This example should work, without the `Delete` on line 29  https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/OctopusDeploy-Api/blob/aac32d194de7b006c8f5472c6e4611f7644a8a92/Octopus.Client/PowerShell/Targets/DeleteMachinesByRole.ps1